# How to evaluate a named formula as if from another cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like to evaluate a named function in Excel as if evaluated from another cell.

As an example, suppose someone has defined the named formula

```
Foo=COLUMN()
```

So if I were to populate various cells with `=Foo`, I would see

- A1: 1
- B1: 2
- C1: 3

I would like cell D1, say, to have (schematically) `Foo(C1) - Foo(A1)`, i.e. `3-1 = 2`.

Is such a thing even possible?

Answer (score 0):

1. select cell D1
2. go to the named function foo
3. change the formula to `=Column(B1)` or if u insist then to `=Column(C1)-Column(A1)`

By the way, a named range cannot take parameter input.

Comment: To clarify: The actual formula is significantly more involved; I'm trying to avoid inlining it, as it would be very fragile/error-prone. (I'm actually computing a weighted sum of the hypothetical value from multiple other cells)

Comment: I recognize that I could do something horribly hacky like have a VBA script evaluate the named range in every cell I need, then replace the values with the appropriate sums, but I would prefer something that is more demonstrably correct. Given that it's not possible to pass in a parameter to a named range, it looks like I may just be SOL.